# ScriptEngineが読み込むスクリプトの中でJavaの標準APIクラスしか初期化できない

Tags: javascript, java

ScriptEngineクラスを用いて.jsファイルを実行し、
その.jsファイルの中で、自作のJavaクラスを初期化して使いたいと思っています。

ここで記述するJavaScriptファイルでは

```
importPackage(java.lang);
```

のような記述をすればそのパッケージ内のクラスを初期化できるようになりますが、
これはJavaの標準APIクラスだけのようです。

仮に自分で jp というパッケージを作って、
上記の書式でインポートしようとしてもエラーが発生します
(ScriptEngine#eval(String)でその行を読みこむとScriptExceptionが発生する)

何か解決策・代替案等あれば教えてください。

以下がそのソースです。
Main.java

```
package jp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        //スクリプトエンジンを生成し、スクリプトを読み込む
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        load(engine, new File("test.js"));
        //スクリプトを実行
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable)engine;
        try {
            invocable.invokeFunction("printTest", (Object)null);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void load(ScriptEngine engine, File jsFile) {
        try {
            String buffer;
            String out = "";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsFile), "UTF-8"));
            while((buffer = reader.readLine()) != null) out += (buffer + "\n");
            reader.close();
            engine.eval(out);
        } catch(IOException | ScriptException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MyObject.java

```
package jp;


public class MyObject {
    public String getPrintText() {
        return "自分で作ったMyObjectクラスです。";
    }
}
```

test.js

```
importPackage(java.lang);
//エラー
//importPackage(jp);

function printTest() {
    println(new String("Javaの標準APIクラスのStringです"));
    //エラー
    //println(new MyObject().getPrintText());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本家の[Import a class in Scripting java (javax.script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180188/import-a-class-in-scripting-java-javax-script) に同様の質問があります。

要点は、`Packages` を付ける(つまり`Packages.jp`のようにする)ということです。
（`java.lang`のjavaは、`Packages.java`のショートカットになっている）